# Accidentally pushed code from one git repository to another git repository address

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I accidentally pushed code from one git repository to another git repository address. Now I want to undo the push. 
I tried deleting the remote branch which was newly created but still the commits are shown in Sourcetree .Is there any way to revert back to initial state.

Comment: I think you (or an admin) will have to garbage collect all those commits.  Even though you deleted that remote branch, my guess is that its commits could still be found in the reflog.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I dont want to revert to a specific commit . Instead I want to remove commit from other repository.

Comment: Scenario : commit from  Rep B is pushed to Rep A address.  Now I need to remove the pushed commits of Rep B from Rep A.

Comment: Who said anything about reverting?  You deleted the branch, which is part of the solution, but I am telling you that the deleted commits may still be present in the reflog.  You need to flush them out from there as well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did that Still in order to clear the branch , I had to delete all the Tags which where there in the Repository B . Thanks

Comment: Good call on tags, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags which belonged to repository which was pushed to unintended repository address was creating a problem. Once this was deleted, all the commits got removed for the source tree.